# glibc: fclose() on invalid pointer hangs in pthread_once()

Tags: c, glibc, freeze, fclose

I am seeing some strange behaviour in glibc. The code had a bug where it would pass a random pointer to *fclose()*. I would have expect it to crash at this point, but instead it hangs in *pthread_once()*, with the below backtrace. The program does not use any threading.

```
#0  0x000000318180ca38 in pthread_once () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003181109d1c in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003181075d34 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000318107c6fc in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x000000318107d719 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000003181080a4a in calloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000003180c0b0df in _dl_new_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x0000003180c061ac in _dl_map_object_from_fd () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#8  0x0000003180c08563 in _dl_map_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#9  0x0000003180c13861 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#10 0x0000003180c0f304 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#11 0x0000003180c131eb in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#12 0x00000031811305d2 in do_dlopen () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#13 0x0000003180c0f304 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#14 0x0000003181130692 in __libc_dlopen_mode () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#15 0x0000003181109c05 in init () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#16 0x000000318180ca40 in pthread_once () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#17 0x0000003181109d1c in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#18 0x0000003181075d34 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#19 0x000000318107d0b8 in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#20 0x000000318106ba6d in fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

This is on Fedora 19 with *glibc-2.17-20.fc19.x86_64*, and the program is started from systemd with `StandardError=null`, so there's no place for *__libc_message()* to output an error message to.

I've fixed the code, but is that hang a glibc bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm checking similar backtrace in these days, and I believe this is a glibc bug, which has been there for at least 7 years since Ubuntu 8.04.

Basically this happens after a memory corruption occurs, and, unfortunately, __libc_message allocates memory itself. Since the heap has corrupted, it trys to do backtrace again. Finally it results a deadlock in pthread_once().

=EDITED=
I found a tracker for this issue, but it seems to be fixed only in master branch.
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16159

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's not a glibc bug: you're breaking the rules and can get whatever behavior happens to happen. [The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose) says:

> In either case any further access (including another call to `fclose()`) to the stream results in undefined behavior.

It's formally wrong to have some form of expectation as to what's going to happen when triggering undefined behavior. The behavior is *undefined*, that means nobody gets to say what's "right" and what's "wrong".

As to exactly why this happens, that's basically only of interest to glibc implementors. That said, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685128/can-fwrite-fclose-be-called-parallely-from-two-threads-for-the-same-file-descr) hints at an explanation: `fclose()` is thread-safe, so it expects the `FILE` to contain a mutex. You're passing a de-allocated structure, causing the library to use random crap data as a mutex, which locks up. Pretty reasonable.